# How can I print tables in the plot window (or markdown) using kable?

Tags: r, kable

I am trying to print my data using the kable function but i cant get it to print in the plots window, i have attached the code i have used underneath if anyone is able to adapt it. If there is a better way to print tables do also let me know please.

mod1:5 are just linear regression models which would be too much to recreate here

```
 mod_comparason = compare_performance(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, mod5) 
 #print this data in a table
 print(kable(mod_comparason))
```

When i use this code i get what seems to be the formating for the table in the console but no print out;

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left;"> Name </th>
<th style="text-align:left;"> Model </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> AIC </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> AIC_wt </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> BIC </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> BIC_wt </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> RMSE </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> Sigma </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> R2 </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> R2_adjusted </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> R2_conditional </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> R2_marginal </th>
<th style="text-align:right;"> ICC </th>
```

Comment: If you are using `rmarkdown`, specify  `results='asis'` in the chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rmarkdown`, specify `results = "asis"` in the chunk.  Below example shows with and without using the option

````
---
title: "test"
---



```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
print(kable(head(mtcars)))
```

```{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
print(kable(head(mtcars)))
```
````

---

If we want to change the `format` from printing on 'html', change the argument.  According to `?kable`

> format - A character string. Possible values are **latex, html, pipe (Pandoc's pipe tables), simple (Pandoc's simple tables), and rst**. The value of this argument will be automatically determined if the function is called within a knitr document. The format value can also be set in the global option knitr.table.format. If format is a function, it must return a character string.

```
kable(head(iris), "pipe")

| Sepal.Length| Sepal.Width| Petal.Length| Petal.Width|Species |
|------------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|:-------|
|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.9|         3.0|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.7|         3.2|          1.3|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.6|         3.1|          1.5|         0.2|setosa  |
|          5.0|         3.6|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          5.4|         3.9|          1.7|         0.4|setosa  |
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in standard R?

Comment: @Joe it is the format that by default could be different.  If you want, can change it to `kable(head(iris), "pipe")` which returns a table with | as delimiter